# Problem on cardinality of path-connected components .

Tags: general-topology, compactness, cardinals

The problem is :
Does there exist any compact topological space X such that the set of all path-connected components of the space X is exactly aleph-naught ???

Actually, I was thinking about the problem when for a given cardinal number § can we found a space X, satisfying some separation or countable axioms such that the number of (connected/path/quasi) components of X are precisely § ??

I am completely unable to think of any non-trivial topological spaces except discrete topology , and I have tried some known spaces but couldn't find it out .
         Also, please provide me some reference book(s) on these topic(s) .

Comment: Can please someone format this question on LateX or MathJax (as I am completely unable of doing it ) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a compact example with countably many path components, take $X = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is such a space.

For a compact example with any given cardinal number, represent that cardinal number by a well ordered set $X$ that possess a maximal element, and use the order topology on $X$.

If you don't like examples in which the path components are all points, take the cartesian product of any of my examples $X$ with your favorite compact path connected set.

Comment: For a construction without ordinals, you can take a 1-point compactification of a discrete space.

Comment: To Lee Mosher, Sir, does there any compact subset of R^n with the given property ???

Comment: @RabiKumarChakraborty multiply the exampe by $[0,1]$ to get a one-dimensional one in the plane, etc.